# Why does jQuery('<img class="pull-left"/>', { src: '...' }) create an image without src?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue is that I try to create an image using the following code:

```
var $img = jQuery('<img class="pull-left"/>', {
    src: 'images/video.svg'
})
```

Surprisingly, it only creates an `img` element with the class but without `src` attribute. If I then use this:

```
$img.attr('src','images/video.svg');
```

The image then gets its `src` attribute. Why is that? Here's a simple snippet that illustrates the issue:

```js
$img = jQuery('<img class="pull-left"/>',{
    src: 'images/video.svg'
});
alert($img.attr('src'));

$img.attr('src','images/video.svg');
alert($img.attr('src'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official documentation for `jQuery( html, attributes )` says that the first parameter should be [a string defining a single, standalone, HTML element (e.g. `<div/>` or `<div></div>`)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes).

So either remove the class and add it to the parameters objects, or use `attr`:

```
var $img = jQuery('<img/>', {
    src: 'images/video.svg',
    class: 'pull-left'
});
```

#### -- OR --

```
var $img = jQuery('<img class="pull-left"/>');
$img.attr('src', 'images/video.svg');
```

The second approach is suited for situations when you create and  modify the element in different parts of your code.

Comment: Ah, so it considers my expression as an html snippet.. Well, this is kinda reasonable, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work as you need to give the selector an empty element, then add all the properties in the object you provide in the second parameter, like this:

```js
$img = jQuery('<img />',{
    src: 'images/video.svg',
    class: 'pull-left'
});

console.log($img.attr('src'));
console.log($img.attr('class'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```